# Permalinks in conflict

Tags: orchardcms

I am trying to add Bodypart and Autoroutpart to my widget. When I tried to add this widget in a zone, I get following exception.  Permalinks in conflict. "" is already set for a previously created PushWidget so now it has the slug "-2". Can somebody explain me what have I done wrong. Any help on this greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why would you want the AutoroutePart on a widget?

Comment: I am trying to attach a detail view on the widget, when user clicks on the hyperlinks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to use Autoroute on anything, you need to configure the pattern used to generate the new URL, by going to the content type editor and deploying the settings for Autoroute. The pattern that you have in there currently is probably empty or has tokens that evaluate to an empty string. Change it to a pattern that is meaningful for this context.